# How do I make this #wrapper div span the full width of the viewport?

Tags: html, css, wordpress, viewport

I'm modifying a responsive Wordpress theme. At smaller viewport sizes, there is ~10 pixels of space between the edge of the main wrapper div and the right edge of the viewport. Take a look: http://bit.ly/1mt2s0D

How do I make it go away? HTML, body, and wrapper divs are all set to 100% width. Padding and margin are set to 0.

Other people have had this issue, but their solutions haven't worked for me. Here's one: [Can't get a div background colour to fill full width of viewport](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11986272/cant-get-a-div-background-colour-to-fill-full-width-of-viewport).

Thanks.

Comment: What's up with that bit.ly URL?

Comment: A quick fix for my problem here was to give the body and HTML tags a "overflow-x: hidden" property, but I still don't know why there is any overflow to begin with.

Comment: That typically means there was an element somewhere on the page that was expanding outside the bounds of the page.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Make a div fill the height of the remaining screen space](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/90178/make-a-div-fill-the-height-of-the-remaining-screen-space)

Answer (score 0):

Your div `.topright` has a `padding-right` set to 5px which is pushing it out past the bounds of the wrapper. At smaller viewports it is 5px wider than everything else.